# Add ListView sections based on c++ QStringList model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The QStringList I'am providing to my QML ListView is displayed correctly. Now I want to reorganize the strings into sections but I'am kind of stuck on what to provide to the section.property ! Is there a minimal change I can make to my code to provide this info ?
Here is my code so far:

C++ Class:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList data  READ getData WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)

public:
    QStringList getData() const {return m_data;}
    void setData(const QStringList &data);

signals:
    void dataChanged();

private:
    QStringList m_data;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Foo>("MyModule", 1, 0, "Foo");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import MyModule 1.0

Foo{
    id: foo
}
...
ListView {
    id: myView
    model: foo.data
    delegate: Text {text: modelData}
    section {
        property: what should I write in here ?
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Qt you are working with?

Comment: I'am using the last version: Qt 5.4.1

Comment: Have a look to [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-listview-sections-qml.html). You need an additional property OR you can exploit [`section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section.criteria-prop) to have an "address book" sectioning style ("A", "B", "C", ...).